Informations about DApp, Node and much more
I wanted to ask you for an advice, because I am a begginer regardin DApss/Nodes, etc. Your help would me a lot appreciated and thank you in advance for it.
In my Trust Wallet, at "Discover" (bottom right in the app), I added the following DApp/Node - https://cwindi.com/. How can I see7know if this DApp/Node is a scam or not? The mentioned DApp (cwindi) has a lock before the https:, so it should be ok, no? On the other hand, https://cwindi.com/ and https://viefh.com/#/ look the same, which makes me unsecure about the safety.
Today when I wanted to transfer money from my Binance account to my Trust Wallet I got a message that made me totally insecure. RW00475 Scam Alert (High Risk). But was my Trust Wallen, not of from someone else. Could my Trust Wallet be compromised through the connection to the above-mentioned DApp/Node and for this reason Binance sent me this message?
